# open word application inside electron/node js desktop application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ms-word, electron

I'm new to electron(node.js) desktop application. I'm trying to find a way open word application(which is already available in that particular pc or mac) inside the electron desktop application browser-window. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`shell.openItem()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.1.1/docs/api/shell.md#shellopenitemfullpath) to open a Word file in Word (assuming Word is the default application for that file extension). Failing that you can always fall back to launching any application you want via Node's [child process API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html).

Comment: Thanks, but i tried the following                                                               'const shell = require('electron').shell;
const path = require('path');var cp = require("child_process"); cp.exec("C:\\Users\\input\\REF.docx");
  shell.openItem(path.join(__dirname, 'test.docx'));' As you said it is opening the doc in word application. but what i need is open the word application inside my electron app. Thanks again.

Comment: @hp2792: Opening Word inside the Electron app is not possible. It's not the times of IE 6 anymore. If you want to have Word inside the browser these days you're probably after Word Online.

Comment: @DirkVollmar: Thanks for taking your time to explain to me about the evolution of browser. But I'm trying to create a desktop application using electron and node.js. If there is anything like java "org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite" which will allow us to open the client site "Word application" in JFrame. As you said, if it is not possible do something like that in node.js then thats it. thanks for your help.

Comment: @hp2792 It doesn't look like many people have bothered trying to use OLE and NodeJS (not publicly anyway), the only [NPM package](https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole) that provided support for OLE appears to have been abandoned 3 years ago. Anyway, there's nothing like `org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite` in Electron.

Comment: @hp2792: Since Electron is chrome-based you might give this a shot: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en

Comment: @VadimMacagon: Thanks for that information.@Dirk Vollmar: I will try that  too. Thanks for sharing this idea with me.